# Convert var into list

Tags: c#, list

```
var result = nomidb.Where(x => !listnamedataset.Contains(x.nome)).ToList();
```

i want to put all elements into a `public list<nomierrati>nomisbagliati`. nomierrati is a class with properties id and nome. How can i put all elements in var result into nomisbagliati?

Comment: Does `nomisbagliati = nomidb.Where(...).ToList();` work? If the list property already contains a list and you want to add to that list, instead do `nomisbagliati.AddRange(nomidb.Where(...).ToList());`

Comment: Could you show us your `nomierrati` class code?  Maybe you can try to use `Select`?

Comment: public class nomierrati
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string nome { get; set; }


        }

Comment: You could do (but I'm just guessing classes structure) `nomisbagliati.AddRange(result.Select(n=>new nomierrati { id = n.id, nome = n.nome }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When type of data contained in `result` is different from `nomisbagliati`, then what you can do is

```
nomisbagliati.AddRange(
  result.Select(n => new nomierrati 
     { id = n.id,
       nome = n.nome 
     }));
```

Please consider I don't know almost anything about `result`, so I'm just guessing...